# Determine if solr reindex completed successfully?

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, reindex

Last evening I started a full reindex for our Cassandra cluster via the Solr admin web console (I selected "Full Reindex").  Each node in the cluster also runs Solr.

As of about 2 hours ago it appears as though it completed since the web console for each node has "no" besides the indexing line, however I wanted to go through the logs and verify that it completed successfully for each node because the web console for each node has the red circle with a line through it next to "current".

In the past I've seen this and then later had it change to the green checkmark, but I figure if I know what to look for in the logs then that would be a much more convenient and reliable method of determining whether the reindex did in fact complete successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Curl

You can use:
curl -v "http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=STATUS&name=demo.solr

There should be an "indexing" tag in the returned xml

#### Admin Console

You're on the right track. The web admin console is probably the easiest place for you to check if your indexing is complete.
Once your indexing is complete and you're not doing any writes to the table, **indexing** will say no and **current** will have a check mark rather than a crossed red circle. Current represents whether there are any [known changes](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201404.mbox/%3C53483062.2000007@elyograg.org%3E) to the index that have not been soft-committed (remember the autocommit threshold set in solrconfig.xml). So it is possible that your full-reindex is completed but that you are still indexing new data as it is coming in. DSE Search, is --in essence-- always indexing based on C* writes.

Another way you can do a quick sanity check is by doing a wide open *:* query in the query panel for your core and looking at numFound. You would have to have a ballpark idea of how many records you have in your table.

#### Logs

This is a bit involved but here's a summary of what you'll see in the system.out log when you perform a full re-index. If you want to check your logs for confirmation you can. In this case DSP1375Test.index is the name of my core:

Reload files (schema / config):

```
 INFO [http-8983-exec-2] 2015-03-18 08:59:28,725 SolrCoreResourceManager.java (line 382) Reloading core: DSP1375Test.index
 INFO [http-8983-exec-2] 2015-03-18 08:59:28,727 SolrCoreResourceManager.java (line 532) Trying to load resource solrconfig.xml for core DSP1375Test.index by querying from local node with CL QUORUM
 INFO [http-8983-exec-2] 2015-03-18 08:59:28,734 SolrCoreResourceManager.java (line 542) Successfully loaded resource solrconfig.xml for core DSP1375Test.index by querying from local node.
 INFO [http-8983-exec-2] 2015-03-18 08:59:28,946 SolrCoreResourceManager.java (line 532) Trying to load resource schema.xml.bak for core DSP1375Test.index by querying from local node with CL QUORUM
 INFO [http-8983-exec-2] 2015-03-18 08:59:28,951 SolrCoreResourceManager.java (line 542) Successfully loaded resource schema.xml.bak for core DSP1375Test.index by querying from local node.
 INFO [http-8983-exec-2] 2015-03-18 08:59:29,003 SolrCoreResourceManager.java (line 532) Trying to load resource schema.xml for core DSP1375Test.index by querying from local node with CL QUORUM
 INFO [http-8983-exec-2] 2015-03-18 08:59:29,009 SolrCoreResourceManager.java (line 542) Successfully loaded resource schema.xml for core DSP1375Test.index by querying from local node.
 INFO [http-8983-exec-2] 2015-03-18 08:59:29,468 CoreContainer.java (line 472) replacing core: DSP1375Test.index
 INFO [http-8983-exec-2] 2015-03-18 08:59:29,469 SolrCoreResourceManager.java (line 532) Trying to load resource dse-search.properties for core DSP1375Test.index by querying from local node with CL QUORUM
 INFO [http-8983-exec-2] 2015-03-18 08:59:29,474 SolrCoreResourceManager.java (line 548) No resource dse-search.properties found for core DSP1375Test.index by querying from local node.
 INFO [http-8983-exec-2] 2015-03-18 08:59:29,474 SolrCoreResourceManager.java (line 558) Trying to load resource dse-search.properties for core DSP1375Test.index by looking for legacy resources...
 INFO [http-8983-exec-2] 2015-03-18 08:59:29,474 SolrCoreResourceManager.java (line 580) No resource dse-search.properties found for core DSP1375Test.index on any live node.
 INFO [http-8983-exec-2] 2015-03-18 08:59:29,474 DSESearchProperties.java (line 79) Using default DSE search properties for Solr core DSP1375Test.index
 INFO [http-8983-exec-2] 2015-03-18 08:59:29,474 DSESearchProperties.java (line 104) Refreshed DSE search properties for: DSP1375Test.index
 INFO [http-8983-exec-2] 2015-03-18 08:59:29,477 SolrCoreResourceManager.java (line 532) Trying to load resource solrconfig.xml for core DSP1375Test.index by querying from local node with CL QUORUM
 INFO [http-8983-exec-2] 2015-03-18 08:59:29,483 SolrCoreResourceManager.java (line 542) Successfully loaded resource solrconfig.xml for core DSP1375Test.index by querying from local node.
 INFO [http-8983-exec-2] 2015-03-18 08:59:29,495 SolrCoreResourceManager.java (line 666) Wrote resource 'solrconfig.xml.bak' for core 'DSP1375Test.index'
 INFO [http-8983-exec-2] 2015-03-18 08:59:29,495 SolrCoreResourceManager.java (line 532) Trying to load resource schema.xml for core DSP1375Test.index by querying from local node with CL QUORUM
 INFO [http-8983-exec-2] 2015-03-18 08:59:29,498 SolrCoreResourceManager.java (line 542) Successfully loaded resource schema.xml for core DSP1375Test.index by querying from local node.
 INFO [http-8983-exec-2] 2015-03-18 08:59:29,503 SolrCoreResourceManager.java (line 666) Wrote resource 'schema.xml.bak' for core 'DSP1375Test.index'
```

Start Re-index:

```
 INFO [SolrSecondaryIndex DSP1375Test.index index reloader.] 2015-03-18 08:59:29,508 AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java (line 1390) Reindexing on keyspace DSP1375Test and column family index
  INFO [SolrSecondaryIndex DSP1375Test.index index reloader.] 2015-03-18 08:59:29,508 AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java (line 1390) Reindexing on keyspace DSP1375Test and column family index
 INFO [SolrSecondaryIndex DSP1375Test.index index reloader.] 2015-03-18 08:59:29,523 SecondaryIndex.java (line 190) Submitting index build of DSP1375Test.index for data in 
 INFO [SolrSecondaryIndex DSP1375Test.index index reloader.] 2015-03-18 08:59:29,528 AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java (line 1006) Executing hard commit on index DSP1375Test.index
```

Build Index Complete:

```
 INFO [SolrSecondaryIndex DSP1375Test.index index reloader.] 2015-03-18 08:59:29,530 SecondaryIndex.java (line 208) Index build of DSP1375Test.index complete

 INFO [http-8983-exec-3] 2015-03-18 08:59:29,765 SolrDispatchFilter.java (line 672) [admin] webapp=null path=/admin/cores params={slave=true&deleteAll=true&name=DSP1375Test.index&distributed=false&action=RELOAD&reindex=true&core=DSP1375Test.index&wt=javabin&version=2} status=0 QTime=0 
 INFO [http-8983-exec-2] 2015-03-18 08:59:29,782 SolrDispatchFilter.java (line 672) [admin] webapp=null path=/admin/cores params={deleteAll=true&action=RELOAD&reindex=true&_=1426683568718&core=DSP1375Test.index&wt=json} status=0 QTime=1058
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but since the Solr reindexing [directly wired up to Cassandra secondary index rebuiding](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/datastax-enterprise-cassandra-with-solr-integration-details), my guess is that if Cassandra has finished index rebuild, then Solr is all good too.